# How to Stop and Start EC2 Instance using boto3 and lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lambda, boto3

I want to start and stop EC2 instances using Lambda Function

I am able to start and stop EC2 instances using the Instance ID but How can I do the same for Instance name, I am trying to do this because my end-user doesn't know what is instance-id they are only aware of Instance name

below is my code which is working fine for instance ID

```
import json
import boto3

region = 'us-east-1'
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    instances = event["instances"].split(',')
    action = event["action"]
    
    if action == 'Start':
        print("STARTing your instances: " + str(instances))
        ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
        response = "Successfully started instances: " + str(instances)
    elif action == 'Stop':
        print("STOPping your instances: " + str(instances))
        ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
        response = "Successfully stopped instances: " + str(instances)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response)
    }
```

Events I am passing for stopping

```
{
  "instances": "i-0edb625f45fd4ae5e,i-0818263a2152a23bd,i-0cd2e17ba6f62f651",
  "action": "Stop"
}
```

Events I am passing for starting

```
{
  "instances": "i-0edb625f45fd4ae5e,i-0818263a2152a23bd,i-0cd2e17ba6f62f651",
  "action": "Start"
}
```

Comment: Instance name is not unique. You may have many instances with same name. Then you want to stop all of them?

Comment: yes make sense right

Comment: So instead of instance-ids, you are going to pass instance names?

Comment: yes we have instance name only ,because end user don't know about instances IDs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instance name is based on tag called `Name`. So to get instance ids based on name you have to filter instances by tags. Below is one possible way of doing that:

```
import json
import boto3

region = 'us-east-1'

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def get_instance_ids(instance_names):

    all_instances = ec2.describe_instances()
    
    instance_ids = []
    
    # find instance-id based on instance name
    # many for loops but should work
    for instance_name in instance_names:
        for reservation in all_instances['Reservations']:
            for instance in reservation['Instances']:
                if 'Tags' in instance:
                    for tag in instance['Tags']:
                        if tag['Key'] == 'Name' \
                            and tag['Value'] == instance_name:
                            instance_ids.append(instance['InstanceId'])
                            
    return instance_ids

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    instance_names = event["instances"].split(',')
    action = event["action"]

    instance_ids = get_instance_ids(instance_names)

    print(instance_ids)

    if action == 'Start':
        print("STARTing your instances: " + str(instance_ids))
        ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instance_ids)
        response = "Successfully started instances: " + str(instance_ids)
    elif action == 'Stop':
        print("STOPping your instances: " + str(instance_ids))
        ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instance_ids)
        response = "Successfully stopped instances: " + str(instance_ids)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response)
    }
```

Comment: Be aware that Names have not to be unique and this will start/stop all of them (with the same name) at once

Comment: @lipek Yes, as names are not unqiue. Otherwise have to ask your client to get you instance id, not name. Or maybe your client is sure he/she does not have duplicate names?

Comment: @lipek Oh. I thought you were the OP. So my comment is probably out of context:-)

Comment: @RahultheSWE What do you mean? Did the answer worked?

Comment: I'm getting keyError

Answer (score 1):

There is a highly scalable and cost-effective solution developed by AWS. Check it at https://aws.amazon.com/es/solutions/implementations/instance-scheduler-on-aws/.

It is easily deployed using CloudFormation templates and managed by a cli. Last but not least, it operates over multiple accounts, and that way you can have a lot of ec2 instances (and RDS instances too) spread over multiple accounts and this solution will save you a lot of effort.

Comment: but it will come up with some cost, as designing the whole system we always prefer to save money,that is more important,but thanks for your response

Comment: I use it and it's very cheap for me (in my team we manage about 20 instances) as you can use lambda 24 times (hourly) a day and a dynamo table with a few entries... nothing else. 
So I recommend you if your number of instances increases because you will get a strong control over the solution, but actually, if you just have a few instances, it makes more sense use just a lambda